# Java null checks on Javabean nested attributes

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm working with BigDecimal calculations and read it's better to check for null than to surround with try catch. For example:

```
private BigDecimal computeSpringRateBoltWasher() {
    if (boltWasher.getMaterial().getElastic_modulus() != null) {
      BigDecimal term1 = boltWasher.getMaterial().getElastic_modulus().multiply(BigDecimal.TEN);
        // other equations 
      return results;
    }
   return null;
}
```

But here I get a nullPointerException because the bolt washer's material is null.  How do I cleanly check for null on the Material then on the Elastic Modulus?

Does it boil down to something like this?  I'll have a few other attributes in this method that I'll need to check and it could get messy.

```
private BigDecimal computeSpringRateBoltWasher() {
    if (boltWasher.getMaterial() != null) {
       if (boltWasher.getMaterial().getElastic_modulus() != null) {
```

Comment: Use &&: `if (boltWasher.getMaterial() != null && boltWasher.getMaterial().getElastic_modulus() != null)`. Is it valid for a boldWasher to have a null material? Is it valid for a material to have a null elsatic modulus? Is it valid to call that method if any of those fields is null? If it's not, then you shouldn't check for anything: the calling code has a bug, and throwing a NullPointerException is the right thing to do. Returning null just hides the bug in the calling code.

Comment: you can and all your checks in one, such as `if (boltWasher != null && boltWasher.getMaterial() != null && boltWasher.getMaterial().getElastic_modulus() != null)` or as i recommend is to create a method in `boltWasher `class which validate your object like `public boolean valid(){ /*** return  do your and checks here **/}`

Comment: OK cool. I see that the order matters and that you must list the top level first.

Comment: it's valid to have null material while the engineer is in progress of entering all bolt/nut/plate values.  There is a calculation results page (jsf using MathJax) that would show ? for all equations currently unsolvable.  I'm porting a Mathcad workbook to JSF.  Ultimately yes, there needs to be a material set to get final results.

Answer (score 1):

Simplify your code, (extract boltWasher.getMaterial() to a new variable, do your code more readable).
If you are writing an API or an application provide validations, Apache commons comes in handy. I would do this, see the comments in the code:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

/**
 * Any
 */
 public class Any {

    private BigDecimal anything;

    public void setAnything(BigDecimal anything){
            this.anything = anything;
    }

    /**
     * computeSpringRateBoltWasher. Explain what this method is intended to do.
     *
     * @return the result of the calculation
     * @throws NullPointerException when anything is null, explain what other fields could cause an exception
     */
    public BigDecimal computeSpringRateBoltWasher() {
            Validate.notNull(this.anything, "Anything must not be null");
            //Validate.notNull(somethingElse, "Something else must not be null");
            BigDecimal term1 = this.anything.multiply(BigDecimal.TEN);
            //Do more things with term1 and return a result
            return term1;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){

            Any any = new Any();
            any.setAnything(new BigDecimal(10));
            BigDecimal result = any.computeSpringRateBoltWasher();
            System.out.println(result);


            any.setAnything(null);
            result = any.computeSpringRateBoltWasher();
            System.out.println(result);

    }
 }
```

This will produce the following ouput (you decide to catch the Runtime exception)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Anything must not be null
    at org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:222)
    at Any.computeSpringRateBoltWasher(Any.java:20)
    at Any.main(Any.java:36)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using java 7 or 8, you could check for nulls with [`Objects.requireNonNull()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T,%20java.lang.String)) method:

```
private BigDecimal computeSpringRateBoltWasher() {
    // Perform non-null validations
    // These will throw NullPointerException in case the argument is null
    Objects.requireNonNull(
        boltWasher.getMaterial(), 
        "Material cannot be null");
    Objects.requireNonNull(
        boltWasher.getMaterial().getElastic_modulus(), 
        "Elastic modulus cannot be null");

    BigDecimal term1 = 
        boltWasher.getMaterial().getElastic_modulus().multiply(BigDecimal.TEN);

    // other equations 

    return results;
}
```

Depending on the *contract* of your operations, you shouldn't return `null` when an argument is `null`, because in this case you'd be hiding the error. If it's not valid for a material or an elastic modulus to be `null`, then throw `NullPointerException` by using `Objects.requireNonNull()`.

On the other hand, if it's valid for a material or an elastic modulus to be `null`, then you should handle this case carefully. For this, you could use either multiple `if` statements, or some validation library.

Comment: unfortunately we haven't upgraded to 7 or 8 yet.  Initially all results variables are set to Null.  Until all inputs have been entered by the user, I want to keep the results to null.  A JSF page is updated with AJAX showing a bunch of engineering equations and results.  Keeping results to Null indicates to user that they are not done entering inputs.  See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8 Optional, the nested null check can be done in a more elegant and readable way:

```
Optional.ofNullable(boltWasher)
    .map(bolt -> bolt.getMaterial())
    .map(mat -> mat.getElastic_modulus)
    .orElse(null)
```